# VS.Net Post Build Event

Tags: visual-studio, events, post, build

I have a very simple problem.

My VS.Net output DLL needs to be registered as a COM Callable Wrapper.
This is a DLL that takes forever to unregister and register.

Is there any way I can do this unregister and register in the post build event only when I run the application rather than doing it after everytime I compile successfully?

Thanks

Narayanan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second empty project file.  Add a Reference to your original project.  Put your post-build scripts in the second project file.

Choose the original project to compile without post-build.

Choose the second project to compile with post-build.